# Application Template on Blender 2.8 - Not working?

Tags: customization, system

I´ve followed the application template install guide from the official manual:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html#app-templates

Yet I don´t see my splash screen or my configurations automatically loaded. 
What other steps I need to take to make the application template run?
Are custom splash screens deprecated?
[image]

Comment: Even I have same issue. I raised a bug. You can find more information about it here : https://developer.blender.org/T70812

Comment: Marvelous. Thank you for the support. It had not occurred to me to report it.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (Jan 25 2020) Blender 2.83 alpha has been fixed to receive Application Templates again from the "blender" top left icon in the UI. Later when activated, the Application template can start from the "...." on the startup splash screen.